# Why is this macro not printing PDFs correctly

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow up to a previous question about Print to PDF, I've got my macro to run without errors, However, it isn't doing exactly what I want. It appears to be plugging in each value from my drop down list into the correct Cell, but only printing the very last PDF.

I want my macro to

1. Plug the first dropdown value in the correct cell
2. Let the formulas calc
3. Print that page to PDF and save it to the right file path
4. Repeat 1-3 for each value in the drop down list

How do I adjust the Macro to do this?

```
Sub Print_To_PDF()
Sheets("MS Wall Summary Daily View").Activate
    Dim vRws As Long, vRng As Range
    Dim d As Range, d8 As Range, Wst As Worksheet
    Dim fPathFile As String

fPathFile = [NewStoreRollout]
Set Wst = Worksheets("MS Wall Summary Daily View")
Set d8 = Wst.Range("D8")

With Wst
   vRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set vRng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(vRws, "A"))
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$C$2:$M$116"

End With
For Each d In vRng.Cells

d8 = d
Wst.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPathFile, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next d

MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

The file path is:
[image]

Where the value in P7 is linked to D8 on the other tab, where the drop down gets plugged in, so this should create a unique file path ever time the value in the drop down is changed.

Comment: Are you sure you are not exporting all of them but just overwriting the previous file? Your file name needs to be dynamic

Comment: What program are you running VBA from? Excel?

Comment: I do have a dynamic file path. Yes Excel

Comment: Did I do that correctly? I'm new to the site

Comment: You accepted my answer, which indicates that out of all the answers there are you found mine most useful. If another answer comes along which you find better you are always free to unmark my answer as accepted and mark another answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dynamic filepath to ensure that every file is saved separately. You tried to accomplish this by using a named range as reference for your filepath variable:

```
Dim fPathFile As String

fPathFile = [NewStoreRollout]
```

This stores the value of `[NewStoreRollout]` into `fPathFile`. This however doesn't create some kind of link between your variable `fPathFile` and your named range. In order to pull the most recent value of your named range you need to update your variable every iteration of the loop you are running. You should do this before you use the variable to save the pdf file. You can update the value by assigning it again just like you did the first time.

```
For Each d In vRng.Cells

d8 = d
fPathFile = [NewStoreRollout] 'Update the value of fPathFile to create unique files to save
Wst.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fPathFile, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next d
```

To acomplish this I inserted the row `fPathFile = [NewStoreRollout]` right after the row `d8 = d` in your original code.